# How can I avoid "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'usedrandomnumber' referenced before assignment" in my code?

Tags: python, loops, variables

I currently have a code which is used to make the computer guess the number in my head. I keep getting an error because I am using a variable multiple times in one line.

```
import random

N = int(input())

Low = 0
High = N

p=False

guess = random.randint(Low, High)
print(guess)

def get_response():
    response = input()
    global p
    if response == 'l':
        high = guess - 1
        guess = random.randint(Low, high)
        print(guess)

    elif response == 'h':
        low = guess + 1
        guess = random.randint(low, High)
        print(guess)

    elif response == 'c':
        print("He got it")
        p=True
```

How could I solve this problem and how could I loop this? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: That code shouldn't cause the error you're getting; you never even use the variable `usedrandomnumber` in the example despite that being the cause.

Comment: That error message tells you what's wrong: you tried to use that variable before you gave it a value.  Since the code you posted doesn't illustrate the problem, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

you do not call the function it will do nothing

p dose not need to be global as there is no local to shadow it

also p looks like a flag to stop iterating but this is not needed as a break

statement can stop a while(True)

there is no usedrandomnumber and so no UnboundLocalError

```
print('think of a integer in the range [0,100]')
low, high = 0, 100
while(True):
    guess = (low + high)//2 # // int div
    cmd = input('is it %d [Yes(y), higher(h), lower(l)]\n>>> ' % guess)
    if cmd[0].lower()=='y':
        break
    elif cmd[0].lower()=='l':
        high = guess - 1
    elif cmd[0].lower()=='h':
        low = guess + 1
    else:
        print('please answer with "y", "h", or "l" ')
print("I win! your number is %d"%guess)
```

in short you need a loop to look for the number

prints to give instructions

input to get the command form the user
cmd[0] will get the first letter of the command to distinguish them
.lower() will lowercase to the commands are not case sensitive